# Converting match object to string in perl6

Tags: string, match, raku, coercion

I was trying to convert a match object to a string in perl6. The method Str on a match object is defined as:

```
method Str(Match:D: --> Str:D)
```

I would think I could use Str($match) to accomplish this. And it seems to convert it to a string, but I'm getting an error using the string with the following code:

```
my $searchme = "rudolph";
my $match = $searchme ~~ /.*dol.*/;
say $match.WHAT;
my $test1 = Str($match);
say $test1.WHAT;
say $test1;
```

With the output:

```
(Match)
(Str)
```

With the error:

> Cannot find method 'gist': no method cache and no .^find_method in
>   block  at .code.tio line 6

However, if I run:

```
my $searchme = "rudolph";
my $match = $searchme ~~ /.*dol.*/;
say $match.WHAT;
my $test1 = $match.Str;
say $test1.WHAT;
say $test1;
```

I get no error and the result:

```
(Match)
(Str)
rudolph
```

Is this a bug or me misunderstanding how it works?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It's a bug. Perhaps you just golfed [this](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1800). `dd $test1;` instead of `say $test1;` is helpful in that it displays `BOOTStr $test1 = (BOOTStr without .perl method)`. Based on that I [searched the rakudo repo for `BOOTStr`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?q=BOOTStr) and that led to the above issue. I will try to golf it further but thought I'd post this comment in the meantime.

Comment: As an aside, I usually use `~` to coerce a match to a string. `my $text = ~$match`

Answer (score 8):

I'm writing this up as an answer even though it's actually an incomplete discussion of a bug, so not at all normal SO fare. The alternative of lots of comments doesn't seem better.

---

It's a bug. Perhaps you just golfed [this](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1800).

`dd $test1;` instead of `say $test1;` is helpful in that it displays `BOOTStr $test1 = (BOOTStr without .perl method)`.

Based on that I [searched the rakudo repo for `BOOTStr`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?q=BOOTStr) and that led to the above issue.

Golfing it further leads to:

```
say $ = Str(Match.new);
```

Note that these are all fine:

```
say Str(Match.new);
say $ = Int(Match.new);
say $ = Str(Date.new: '2015-12-31');
```

It appears to be a combination of leaking some implementation details regarding how Rakudo/NQP/MoarVM bootstrap; `Match` being an NQP object; `Str()` on that being wonky; and assigning it to a `Scalar` container (the `$` is an anonymous one) making that wonkiness visible.

I'll add more when/if I figure it out.

Comment: Great, thanks. Clears it up for me. I'll assume it is that bug and not post it. Cheers